# Find a prime number p that is simultaneously expressible in the forms:

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences, legendre-symbol

I´ve been dealing with this problem for almost a weak and I still can't find a solution:

Find a prime number p that is simultaneously expressible in the forms $x^2 +y^2 , a^2 + 2b^2 , t^2 + 3s^2 $ of course x,y,a,b,t and s are integers.

I've been reading some sources and I´ve found that a prime number have to  fulfill some requierments in order to be expresed as one of the equations above, for example:

$ p=x^2+y^2  \iff p\equiv1(mod\ 4)$

$ p=x^2+2y^2  \iff p\equiv1,3(mod\ 8)$

$p=x^2+3y^2  \iff p\equiv1(mod\ 3)$

I tried to solve these linear congruences but I couldn't find anything, and I also tried to use the lengendre symbol to see if there was any relation I could conclude from there. At the end I was just trying by trial and error to see if maybe I could find it, but so far I only know that 41 and 17 can be express as $3^2 +(2)4^2 , 4^2 + 5^2$ and $1^2 + 4^2 , 3^2 + (2)2^2$ respectively.

I would really appreciate any hitn or advice, you cand porvide me in order to solve the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note you can't have $p\equiv 3 \bmod 8$ and $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ together.

Answer (score 1):

Your system of congruences is equivalent to
$$ p \equiv 1 \mod 24$$

The first such prime $p$ is $p = 73$, and indeed, we have that
$$\begin{align*}
73  & = 8^2 + 3^2 \\
    & = 1^2 + 2 \cdot 6^2 \\
    & = 5^2 + 3 \cdot 4^2
\end{align*}$$